# Webkit: CSS force hardware acceleration for 2D transforms without using 3D CSS properties

Tags: css, 3d, hardware-acceleration, css-transforms

Is there anyway of forcing hardware acceleration on 2D transform using CSS in webkit without using 3D (e.g. `translateZ(0)`) (as per [Are 2D transforms hardware accelerated in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824824/are-2d-transforms-hardware-accelerated-in-mobile-safari)).

I'm finding the issue with `position: fixed` elements, where the element is set to something equivalent to `position: absolute`, so not positioned relative to the viewport, rather it ends up positioned relative to the parent container (as explained in this article http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/).

I'm choosing hardware acceleration as the background tends to flicker white on transitions in iOS, in a similar way as this bug outlines https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2856.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 3d transform value to null in addition to your 2d transform value :

```
el {
    transform: 2DValue(val) 3DValueSetToNull(0);
    transform: 2DValue(val);
}
```

Which in real CSS can make something like :

```
div {
    /* translateZ(0) will not interfere with the rotate value */
    /* Also with -webkit-, -moz-, -o- */
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateZ(0);
    /* Compatibility for older (yep) browsers */
    /* Also with -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o- */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Be sure to use a 3D transform value that will not interfere with your 2D transform value.

PS : The 3d transform values are :

- translate3d(x, y, z)
- translateZ(z)
- scale3d(sx, sy, sz)
- scaleZ(sz)
- rotateX(angle)
- rotateY(angle)
- rotate3d(x, y, z, angle),
- perspective(p)
- matrix3d(…)

Comment: Thanks - those values are all 3D CSS properties, I'm looking for a value that *does not* apply a 3D transform, but does force hardware acceleration. 3D transforms, even with a value that does not affect the positioning of the element, force `position:fixed` elements to be positioned relatively to the first `position:relative` parent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting `backface-visibility: hidden` does the trick. I've confirmed this only for chrome, using the [fps-counter](http://www.thechromesource.com/how-to-activate-the-frames-per-second-counter-in-google-chrome/).

```
.3d-accelerate {  
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The FPS counter doesn't show up with only `transition`. It does shows up when adding `translate: transform3d(0, 0, 0)`. I also shows up with just `backface-visibility`.

Comment: Looks like this could be the right answer, would need to test on test case.